# How to set execution policy in PowerShell quietly, without asking?

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following command.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

It asks me if I'm sure and if I yes it, it sets the policy just as supposed to. I wonder, however, how I'm supposed to execute the command so that the computer doesn't ask me to confirm.

I've googled the issue and there's a flag [*-Confirm*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) but using it produces an additional confirmation request. What would be the opposite of it, i.e. something like this (quacky typo intended)?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -JustDoWhatWeTellYouForDucksSake
```

Comment: `-Force` is the switch you're looking for, see [the documentation in TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy).

Comment: @briantist It works. I thought `-Force` was for pushing the command to the different scopes at once. I stand corrected. You might want to post the comment as a reply so it can be accepted.

Comment: I wrote it as a comment because I voted to close the question. Since this is documented clearly, and it's in line with the generally accepted uses of `-Force`, I don't feel like this question will be all that helpful to others. If you agree, you could also just close it directly.

Comment: @briantist I'm prone to agree with you. Are you suggesting that I **vote** on closing it? I'm not sure how to close it otherwise...

Comment: As the asker, you don't have to vote, you can just **delete** it (for others the option is close, for you it's delete I think).

Comment: `-Force` is correct in this context but just a note that if you use the `-Confirm` flag in the future the correct syntax to *remove* the confirmation prompt from most cmdlets is `-Confirm:$false`

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Now you've made the situation a bit messy. I was happy to close/remove my question as it was very straightforwardly answerable from the docs as pointed out in the other comment. But now... I see certain value to keep it, especially if we post your comment as a reply to be accepted. What do you think?

Comment: I formatted my comment as an answer, as far as it being worthwhile or not I'll leave that up to whoever reviews it since I think it should still be in the queue to be reviewed/closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Briantist pointed out in this case you want to use the `-Force` switch to suppress the prompt.  However for future reference in most cases the correct syntax to remove the confirmation prompt from most cmdlets is `-Confirm:$False`

Comment: I would argue that in most cases, confusingly, `-Confirm:$false` is _not_ the correct approach and often doesn't work. That is specifically for situations where the confirm impact is causing a specific type of confirmation prompt. Cmdlets that always prompt typically use `-Force` to suppress all prompts. In my experience `-Force` is almost always the correct one to use.

Comment: What @briantist wrote in the above comment sounds more correct to me. `-Confirm` corresponds to the `ConfirmImpact` [parameter attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.confirmimpact.aspx) and `$ConfirmPreference` variable.

Comment: looking over the default cmdlets it looks like your right, I was basing my answer on experience with third party modules(primarily PowerCli) but that's likely out of scope for this question...

Answer (score 10):

Here is one that is slightly better, as this one will work even if you do not have local administrator privileges. However, it only applies to the current Powershell session.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -Force
```

Comment: Does it work **always**? At the moment I'm local admin on my computer so I didn't have to force anything. How limited right can I have and still be able to use your suggestion? Also - even if I always am able to set the policy that way on process, won't it be overridden by other settings made by the admin?

Comment: In theory, you might be able to specifically stop that particular execution policy override, but I have not seen an effective way to restrict it as of yet. That means yes, it should always work. As long as you have access to Powershell, you should be able to utilize this execution policy bypass. I am not sure if this will function on a guest account, but it is what I used when I can only run Powershell as a normal user. I do not expect to see the utilization of external administrator settings to override such execution for at least a while yet.

Comment: I'm giving you +1 for the hint and elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set the policy to unrestricted, but then whitelist whatever fileserver you're running a script from.  There's probably a gpo way to do this too.  The New-ItemProperty -Type parameter isn't easily found in the docs.

```
new-item -path   'hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\stackoverflow.com\server' -force > $null
new-itemproperty 'hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\stackoverflow.com\server' * -type DWORD -force > $null
```